# What's the best way for me to dual boot linux/Win 8.1 in my Dell Inspiron 14z laptop

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1, multi-boot

So, I happen to have a Dell Inspiron 14z laptop. Unfortunately, like most laptops these days, it comes with a rather bizarre partition plan from the manufacturer, which I myself do not fully comprehend. I have the impression the 2nd drive is an SSD. I had the impression it was 32GB but the windows partition manager seems to think it's only 8. The disk models, as displayed in the Device Manager are:

- ST500LT012-9WS1
- LITEONIT LMT-32

While the following is the info given by the windows partition utility.

[image]
What I want to do is install a linux distro creating the 3 usual partitions (/,/home and /swap) which I have already done on my desktop and have no problem with. The question is the following:
Will I be able to simply add more **primary** partitions on this drive and simply ignore the ones added by the OEM?
If not, what can else can I do (adding secondary partitions maybe?) and how will it affect my options/performance? Also, is my SSD really 8GB and what is it used for in the current setup? I was hoping to use it for Linux as a whole if Windows don't use it at all but 8GB seem a bit restricted.
As a note I don't really use the backup utilities/partitions provided by Dell, however the OS seems to use the "Intel RapidStart" utility which I have no idea how it works.

EDIT: Upon experimentation I have familiarized myself with some of the technicalities and issues that might clarify the problem here. I installed Linux Mint successfully but booting is not working as it should.

- The disk has a **GPT** structure, not MBR. According to multiple sources that means GRUB cannot operate. I would rather keep the GPT as it's more modern and allows more primary partitions, either by finding a way to use GRUB, another linux boot loader or simply dual boot properly from the windows boot manager.
- My laptop has **UEFI** booting options running instead of CMS/BIOS(legacy), though can be changed to legacy mode. Both can be done with safe booting off.
- Installing GRUB (from the initial setup wizard of my Mint distro) on /sda/ doesn't seem to work. I can boot into Mint but to do that I need to *change into legacy options and pick the "Hard Drive" entry which then automatically boots into Linux without going through GRUB* (which presumably fails to start).
- I took a look in [this](http://thpc.info/dual/7/db_mint12_bcd_on_win7.html) (probably not 100% appropriate) guide and used the EasyBCD tool that allows you to add entries in the Windows boot loader. I did, taking the automatically generated settings of the entry and changing the "C:" option to "BOOT" as it was the only one that made sense from the dropdown menu EasyBCD gave me.
- Clearly this is highly impractical and I need to setup a boot loader for dual booting with functional entries, preferably with the ability to add another OS later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You can right click your disk (Disk 0, not partition) and choose "Convert to GPT disk". This will allow you to create up to 128 primary partitions. I have done something like this month ago and it looks like Debian 7 installer supports GPT disks.</s>

Edited.

You have 6 primary partitions on one disk, so this must be GPT partition layout. It supports up to 128 primary partitions instead of 4 (in normal layout).

I would suggest you to resize 448.9GB partition and make some free space for linux parition(s). If there is no "Shrink partition" option under partition right-click - you have to convert your disk to dynamic. Dynamic disks is mature and stable technology used in windows servers, so no worries - this is not something weird, exotic etc.

You can also use that 8GB disk, but keep in mind that Debian with Gnome will eat a lot space (4-5GB).

And there is one more thing - I think using SSD for swap space is bad idea. It may significantly reduce your SSD drive lifespan (if swap will be used).

However if you want to put swap on SSD - read this first:

> **Swap Space on SSDs**
>
> One can place a swap partition on an SSD. Most modern desktops with an
>   excess of 2 Gigs of memory rarely use swap at all. The notable
>   exception is systems which make use of the hibernate feature. The
>   following is a recommended tweak for SSDs using a swap partition that
>   will reduce the "swappiness" of the system thus avoiding writes to
>   swap:
>
> ```
> # echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
> ```
>
> Or one can simply do as recommended in the [Maximizing Performance
>   article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Maximizing_performance#Swappiness):
>
> ```
> /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
> vm.swappiness=1
> vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
> ```

I pasted this from Arch Linux wiki ([link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives#Swap_Space_on_SSDs)).

Comment: Thanks for that last tip, I was thinking swap on SSD would be rather useful. It still seems odd how it came with an SSD that is not used, not to mention that many google results imply the model has 32GB.

Comment: Well, swap works like slow RAM memory, there are many write operations. You can reconfigure system to avoid swap. See my answer again after update.